# Traces of removed packages

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

After executing the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine 1.7
```

I was sure that package had been removed as it showed on free disk space, but then I executed:

```
sudo apt-cache pkgnames wine
```

And it showed various files like :

```
wine-mono0.0.8
wine1.6-amd64
wine-gecko2.21
wine-gecko2.24
wine1.7-amd64
wine-gecko2.34
wine-gecko2.36
wine-gecko2.40
wine1.4
wine1.6
wine1.7
wine1.4-dbg
wine1.4-dev
```

Although it's evident that these files don't take much space, is it possible to remove them completely as I no longer require WINE?

If not how does Linux deal with such leftovers which are bound to pile-up over time?

Comment: Use the `--purge` option to completely remove a package.

Comment: That is the list of packages containing "wine" in their name *that APT knows of*; to get the list of packages containing "wine" in their name *that are installed*: `dpkg-query -f '${Binary:package}\n' -W | grep 'wine'`. After that, you can call `sudo apt-get purge` on the packages in the list (notice that this won't remove packages installed through `dpkg`, those will need to be removed manually).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this instead (use a wildcard):

```
sudo apt-get purge wine-*
```

Always be careful when using wildcards and be sure to review the changes before accepting them by choosing "Y".

Furthermore, the command you ran: `sudo apt-cache pkgnames wine` only shows a list of available packages not files or installed applications.

To view installed applications, you can run the following:

```
dpkg -l | grep wine
```

To view any files, run this instead:

```
sudo find / -name "wine*" | grep wine
```

Don't worry about the icon results for .svg and .png files as they have nothing to do with any installed application but are a part of the icon theme sets.